# Green/pink flickering fuzz on my monitor (looks like The Matrix way off in the distance)

Tags: display

I have an Asus laptop, connected to an external monitor via HDMI.  With a grey background, there is a subtle green flickering fuzz.  It sort of looks like "The Matrix" way off in the distance, moving really fast.

I've tried using an old-fashioned monitor cable, from what I recall it had the exact same problem. I also tried a different monitor and I think same thing.

With most colors, it looks fine.  With light blue, there is a pink fuzz sometimes, not green. It's really pretty annoying.  I'm not sure if it's the connection that's bad, or the driver, or what.

Could the Matrix be inside my computer?  Should I blame Asus?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Morpheus will be contacting you soon, Neo.